# Should I use standart autorization methods in Java EE site?

Tags: java, authorization

I tried to use standart authorization mechanizm using Glassfish/Realms, but it is very strange. it is very inconvenient and inflexible.
The only suitable variant of authorization - FORM, and I must create separated login and login_error pages for use it. I don't like such structure of my site.
I must create structures with data duplication in my database, or a few views. It seems strange.
Should I use it? Or I must create my own bicycle?

/sorry 4 my english/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/ You get a lot out of the box!

Comment: Tnx.I'm just learning. I know, I can use frameworks, but now I want to know, is standart security mechanizm really unusable?